# How to update jersey to 2.7 in glassfish

Tags: jersey, glassfish-4

I am using glassfish4.0 as my application server. The Rest Webservice implementation of glassfish is Jersey. As I known Jersey has been upgraded to 2.7 but the version of glassfish plugged one is 2.0.

How to upgrade the Jersey to 2.7 in my glassfish4.0 application server? And also for other JavaEE implementations, such as JSF?